# Query effective ssh (client) config from the command line

Tags: linux, command-line, ssh, shell-script

Is there any way to query the effective `ssh` (client) configuration?

Specifically: can I determine e.g. whether there's an entry for a given host, what's the `ProxyJump` or `User` setting for that host etc., without implementing my own config file parsing?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From [`man 1 ssh`](https://man.openbsd.org/ssh#G):

> `-G`
> Causes `ssh` to print its configuration after evaluating `Host` and `Match` blocks and exit.

So, `ssh -G some-host | grep "^proxyjump "` will return the `ProxyJump` directive for `some-host`, if one was specified.